# How much of Jungle Book (2016) is CGI?

Tags: effects, the-jungle-book-2016

In Jungle Book, I could tell the boy was real and the animals were CGI, but the landscape and accessories I could not tell.

For example, Mowgli handles various vines and baskets. Are those real? What about all the plants and trees?

Comment: :you require more explanation then i can provide more because you have not accepted any of the answer.If you feel more explanations you can add in the comment.:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All the locations in the movie are CGI. Favreau mentions this while answering questions on twitter.

> @MonkeyBoy1138 How many of the locations were real, and how many are
>   cgi? They’re looking pretty authentic.
>
> Jon Favreau: None are real. All are CGI. The whole movie was shot in
>   downtown LA. … Mowgli floating down the river on Baloo’s belly singing
>   was difficult to recreate with real physics. Lots of R&D

Source: http://www.slashfilm.com/jungle-book-questions/

Answer (score 4):

Source [Independent UK](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/films/features/the-jungle-book-neel-sethi-interview-sequel-superhero-india-rating-a6986031.html) :

Interview of  Neel Sethi (Mowgli) :

> Sethi(Mowgli) tells an anecdote from filming his favourite scene, *when Mowgli is sat on Baloo’s chest, swimming down a river and singing the “Bare Necessities*”.
>
> “**It is a real scene**," he says. "There’s a **lump of Styrofoam with a
>   piece of carpet on top. It kinda looks like Baloo, which is kinda
>   creepy, but it really looked like that**. I was patting it, and I would
>   jump in the water sometimes.” While he was sat on the belly, *Favreau
>   was acting as Baloo's head and arms, singing along and splashing water
>   up at Sethi*. “It was a lot of fun,” Sethi adds.
>
> “Sometimes they would scan this stuff, create the set and replay it. If there’s somewhere I go more than once, they can make the set, scan it, and then just put a blue screen there. It will look exactly the same. 
>   The film itself is stunning; it is hard to believe it was all shot on a soundstage in LA with the majority of the jungle created in blue screen.
>
> “**We didn’t go out to the jungle at all**,” Sethi says. “**I was just in
>   New York - that’s where I live - and flew to LA and that was just it.
>   It was all blue screen so there was no need for a jungle**. Sometimes
>   there was **set** there; anything I was touching or reacting with was
>   actually there. They had **dirt, and soil, and grass, and trees**.
>
> “**The hardest part to get right was this bit in the mud, where buffalo are charging at me**. I’m not used to the mud. I have to act likes it is a normal thing, getting run over by buffalo. So I just had to act like the buffalo was a problem and not the mud, but it was the mud that was the problem and not the buffalo.
>
> “It would dry everywhere on me because **I’m just wearing a diaper. Then
>   they would have to spray me with cold water** [pretends to spray water],
>   and if I rubbed it the makeup would come off and there would be
>   another 40 minutes putting back on

Answer (score 3):

The end credits of the film are very clear (and somewhat funny):

**Filmed in downtown L.A.**